# How to Code NUnit Custom Constraint in VB

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, nunit

I had coded, successfully compiled and tested an NUnit custom constraint.

Today I returned to the VB project to review the constraint to ensure it does what I want it to and now Visual Studio gives the error:

> Error BC30610 Class 'SPCG_LIB_NUnit_Constraint_ExceptionAndMessage'
>   must either be declared 'MustInherit' or override the following
>   inherited 'MustOverride' member(s): 
>       Constraint: Public MustOverride Overloads Function ApplyTo(Of TActual)(actual As TActual) As
>   ConstraintResult. SPCG_LibraryNUnit   C:\Development\SPCG_LibraryNUnit\SPCG_LibraryNUnit\SPCG_LIB_NUnit_Constraint_ExceptionAndMessage.vb 14  Active

Here's the code with the actual guts of `ApplyTo` removed for clarity.

```
Public Class SPCG_LIB_NUnit_Constraint_ExceptionAndMessage
    Inherits Constraint

    Private m_Actual As Exception

    Private m_ExceptionObj As Exception

    Private m_Message As String

    Public Sub New(Exception As Exception)

        If Exception Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("Exception")
        End If

        m_ExceptionObj = Exception
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Function ApplyTo(Of TActual)(Actual As TActual) As ConstraintResult
        Dim ResultObj As ConstraintResult

        ResultObj = New ConstraintResult(Me, Actual, False)

        Return ResultObj

    End Function

End Class
```

NUnit 3.6.1

Could someone please give an example of how to override `ApplyTo`?

Every combination of `Overrides`, `Overloads`, etc gives me some kind of error.

Also, I tried cutting out the code and then typing in Inherits Constraint statement with the assumption VS would auto-generate the correct syntax for `ApplyTo`. Nope. VB listed errors for the auto-generated `ApplyTo`.

Comment: `Public Overrides Function ApplyTo(Of TActual)(Actual As TActual) As ConstraintResult` should work, according to documentation. What error do you get when you use `Overrides`